# Rails, validate existance of object from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have a simple app with 3 models - Restaurant, Employee, and User.
My Restaurant model has_many employees and I can hire other employees by creating them and giving a value to an attribute user_id of the employee. How to check for the presence of User with id=user_id before saving the new employee? Thank you!

EDIT======= The solution

```
validate :user_exists

  def user_exists
   if User.exists?(self.user_id)
    return true
   else
    self.errors.add(:user_id, "Unable to find this user.")
    return false
   end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a simpler way of doing this since you can validate the belongs_to the association directly:

**In Employee**:

`validates :user, presence: true, message: "could not be found"`

Comment: It's my fault that I didn't put the models but there is no association between the employee and user.However, it might be a good idea to do say that each user has_many employees (doesn't sound good, though..)  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :user_exists, message: "#{user_id} must be a valid user"

  def user_exists
   return false if User.find(self.user_id).nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: Please provide some context instead of just answering with a code block.

Comment: It was almost right. Thanks a lot! However, the message does not work and I had to change the method a bit. Now, I only have to figure out how to fix the error message...

Answer (score 0):

It works with this code(No employee is created when the id is not found) but the error message is not showing...

```
     validate :user_exists

      def user_exists
       if User.exists?(self.user_id)
        return true
       else
        self.errors.add(:error, "Unable to find this user.")
        return false
       end
      end
```

Comment: what about using the :user_id attribute to error message ?

self.errors.add(:user_id, "Unable to find this user.")